# Get partial string match of string Array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of strings and want to find partial string matches using Lodash. I'd like the search to find full matches (such as with `broken`) but also partial matches (such as with `virus` being part of `viruses`)

```
const textToSearch = 'The broken ship that caught fire also had viruses onboard';
const arrayOfKeywords = ['virus', 'fire', 'broken'];
```

So far I have a method that will split the textToSearch into an array and then find full matches using `_.include()`

```
const tokenize = text =>
    text
      .split(/(\w+)/)
      .map(x =>
        _.includes(arrayOfKeywords, x.toLowerCase())
          ? {content: x, type: 'keyword'}
          : x
      );

const tokens = tokenize(textToSearch);
```

Comment: You can use `.some()` but it hardly requires Lodash to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve fuzzy matches is using *[`some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#some)* function with a custom predicate to check for partial matches. Something like:

```js
const textToSearch = 'The broken ship that caught fire also had viruses onboard';
const arrayOfKeywords = ['virus', 'fire', 'broken'];

const tokenize = text =>
  text
    .split(/(\w+)/)
    .map((x) =>
      _.some(arrayOfKeywords, (keyword) => x.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
        ? { content: x, type: 'keyword' }
        : x
    );

const tokens = tokenize(textToSearch);
console.log(tokens);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

<sub>**Footnote:** In case you want to do it without using `lodash`, you can replace `_.some` with [`Array.protoype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)</sub>

Comment: Perfect! that worked like a charm! i knew i was close!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to optimize this and make more readability code is to use RegRex in javascript.

```js
const textToSearch = 'The broken ship that caught fire also had viruses onboard';
const arrayOfKeywords = ['virus', 'fire', 'broken'];
const pattern = new RegExp(arrayOfKeywords.join('|'), 'i');;
const tokenize = text =>
    text
      .split(/(\w+)/)
      .map(x =>
        pattern.test(x)
          ? {content: x, type: 'keyword'}
          : x
      );

const tokens = tokenize(textToSearch);
console.log(tokens);
```